how can I implement the customer account search using ssn, firstname, last name and account id using Jxchange SOAP svc?
Could you please provide some info on the customer account search using ssn, first name, last name and account id using Jxchange SOAP svc? please provide some steps on documentation on how to implement customer search using ssn.
